# iPython - can't import caffe

Tags: python, caffe

I'm trying to run [a realtime multi-person pose estimation](https://github.com/ZheC/Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation) code written in Python. I downloaded the code and after that, I installed ipython via `pip install ipython` and after which, I installed Jupyter via `pip install jupyter`. Now, I had the tools I needed to `ipython notebook` on the python directory of the code.

The server opened (which was neat and all) and I was able to run the `demo.ipynb` file. It had the code there as well as several output images to show how the application works. Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image: code screencap]

So I can see the code and some of the `plt.imshow()` lines and the corresponding output.

However, when I tried to change line 64, to:

```
#test_image = '../sample_image/ski.jpg'
test_image = '../sample_image/upper.jpg'
#test_image = '../sample_image/upper2.jpg'
```

So that it would read a different image, after clicking `Kernel --> Restart & Run All`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

After searching what how to solve it, however, it doesn't seem to be as straightforward as `pip install caffe`.

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, installing caffe is not as simple as "pip"...
Please follow [these installation instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) to install caffe on your machine.

### Update

For [ubuntu >= 17.04](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html), you can

```
~$ sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

or

```
~$ sudo apt install caffe-cuda
```

It is also available for [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/caffe):

```
~$ conda install -c conda-forge caffe
```